# Send Data from Sever to Client with Async TcpListener

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, client, tcplistener

I try to get asyncronous communication between a server and a client in C# with unity.
I found many tutorial to do this sycronous or using asyc sockets but none using tcplistener asyncronously.

I tried the following
for the Server:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
public class TcpListenClientBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TcpListener _listener;
  
    public bool _isReady;
    
    public int _port = 9022;
    

    void Start()
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,
        _port);
        _listener.Start();
        _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(Socket_Connected,
        _listener);
        _isReady = true;
    }
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _listener?.Stop();
        _listener = null;
    }
    private void Socket_Connected(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            var client = (ar.AsyncState as TcpListener).EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
            
            
            var state = new ClientStateObject(client);
            var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello, from TcpServer!");
            client.GetStream().BeginWrite(msg, 0, msg.Length, Send_Complete, null);

            client.GetStream().BeginRead(state.Buffer,0,state.Buffer.Length,Client_Received,state);
            
        }
    }


    private void Client_Received(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            var state = ar.AsyncState as ClientStateObject;
            var bytesIn = state.Stream.EndRead(ar);
            if (bytesIn > 0)
            {
                var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer,0,bytesIn);
                print($"From client: {msg}");
            }
            var newState = new ClientStateObject(state.Client);
            state.Stream.BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, Client_Received, newState);

        }

    }

    private void Send_Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Debug.Log("sending it to the client");
        if (ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("done sending it to the client");
            var client = ar.AsyncState as TcpClient;
            client.GetStream().EndWrite(ar);
        }
    }
}
```

And for the Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

public class TcpClientAsyncBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TcpClient _client;
    
    public string _ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";

    public int _port = 9022;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
       
        _client = new TcpClient();
        _client.Connect(_ipAddress, _port);
        
        var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello, from TcpClient!");
        _client.GetStream().BeginWrite(msg,0,msg.Length,Send_Complete,_client);

        var state = new ClientStateObject(_client);
        _client.GetStream().BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, Client_Received, state);
        yield return null;
    }

    private void Send_Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            var client = ar.AsyncState as TcpClient;
            client.GetStream().EndWrite(ar);
        }
    }

    private void Client_Received(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Debug.Log("receiving");
        if (ar.IsCompleted)
        {
            var state = ar.AsyncState as ClientStateObject;
            var bytesIn = state.Stream.EndRead(ar);
            if (bytesIn > 0)
            {
                var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesIn);
                print($"From Server: {msg}");
            }
            var newState = new ClientStateObject(state.Client);
            state.Stream.BeginRead(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, Client_Received, newState);

        }

    }
}
```

The Server get the Message from the client, but the client is not receiving from the server.
I guess i got something basic wrong here.
Please help me out.

The Client State Object class is

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
public class ClientStateObject
{
    public TcpClient Client { get; }
    public NetworkStream Stream => Client.GetStream();
    public byte[] Buffer { get; }
    public ClientStateObject(TcpClient client,
int bufferSize = 1024)
    {
        Client = client;
        Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is limited because you don't know what the `ClientStateObject` class is.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: The **server receives** a `From client: Hello, from TcpClient!` message from the client, and the **client receives** a `From Server: Hello, from TcpServer!` message from the server. It's working normally, isn't it? Could you please be more specific about what the problem is?

Comment: I my case only the server is receiving the message. The Client is not receiving anything from the server. private void Send_Complete(IAsyncResult ar) from server seems to not be called ever and i dont know why.

Comment: After creating two projects, when I use the code you provided, everything works fine. I don't think it's a code issue, but a computer environment issue?

Comment: Did you test it in Unity?

Comment: Yes Unity version 2021.3.1f1